# How to get unselected option value of bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: javascript, select, bootstrap-4, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

There are some options selected in bootstrap multiselect. Whenever I will unselect any of those selected options, I need the value of unselected option. How can I get this value?

```
<select
    class="form-control bootstrap-selectpicker"
    data-live-search="true"
    data-selected-text-format="count"
    name="colors[]"
    id="colors"
    multiple
    onchange="showValue(this)">
        <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Yellow</option>
        <option value="3">White</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you please include the html of your bootstrap multiselect?

Comment: <select class="form-control bootstrap-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count" name="colors[]" id="colors" multiple onchange="showValue(this)">
        <option  value="1" selected>Red</option>
        <option  value="2" selected>Yellow</option>
        <option  value="3">White</option></select>

Comment: use `onChange` https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ you can see the example on that page, when selecting / deselecting an option, it catches which option has changed

Comment: you can use `$('select#colors option:not(:selected)');` to get the option elements not selected at any given point in time (for example in your onchange event handler.. in that case `$(elementpassedtofunction).find('option:not(:selected)')`) and loop through them to fetch their text or the value